# How to leave product feedback on macOS?

Tags: bug, applecare, macos

I love how Microsoft products have built-in customer feedback (click the smiley face) and wish I could do the same with Apple products, especially macOS.

What is the fastest way to provide feedback on macOS features and bugs?

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate of the question linked above. Thanks @nohillside!

Comment: I still agree that this question is a duplicate, but I think @bmike's answer is unique and adds significant value. It's more about navigating the organization than anything, which is super useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way is on twitter and the support webpage and iOS app. The old bug reporter and feedback mechanisms are there too, but the analogous fast and human interaction method of support is to ping Apple’s customer support and relations staff directly.

I find asking for guidance and training works better than ranting about how awful a bug is, but I’ve seen both get really professional guidance and started using that over the traditional Genius Bar and Apple support pages. Also, often I just didn’t realize how to do something and they’ve been forthcoming when what I face is legitimately a design decision where I need to offer feedback on my use case and why their design decision wasn’t optimal for me. Same with bugs, support can and will escalate to engineering if you don’t have another support path in place as a developer or business partner.

If it’s a bug, you’ll want to bring reproducible steps or ask how to collect the logs they need to analyze the failure. They will steer you to the appropriate avenue whether it’s understnading the feature or asking for traditional feedback or working with AppleCare support to isolate the issue.

I always start with support, then go where they direct:

- https://support.apple.com/
- https://twitter.com/AppleSupport
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-support/id1130498044

Some of those links are in the support pane of About this Mac as well if you prefer to click something from apple directly. The iOS support app is really nice as well, in my experience. It integrates with iMessage and call back quite effortlessly.

Comment: Thanks @bmike. Just to make sure I'm clear, do you recommend starting with support even when I'm sure I'm observing a bug or design decision I disagree with for my use case?

Comment: @Crowder Yes - I always start with support now. They occasionally have a really great workaround and I know when they are convinced it's a bug, they escalate it as well. Then I add the support case notes to the feedback or bug if it doesn't get resolved through AppleCare directly.. (ok - only exception is API / SDK / Xcode type issues when I start with developer support instead of end user support.)

Answer (score 5):

Apple hosts a dedicated webpage on its website to share product feedback:

- [Product Feedback - Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)

Use the above link to share general product feedback with Apple regarding various hardware and software products.

If that doesn't suffice your need, and you'd like to either report bug(s) or request new feature(s), you can do so via dedicated bug reporter here:

- [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com)

You'll need to log in with an Apple ID to do so.

Bug Reporter is preferred, as the concern will be directed to the relevant  product team, and you'll most likely get a feedback regarding the status from them.

Also, a new feature request or a bug fix is most likely to happen, contingent to the number of unique bug reports filed. So, Bug Reporter is preferred over Product feedback page.

Filing a bug report is termed as filing a **Radar** in Apple.

---

**P.S.**: There's an official webpage outlining recommended best practises when sharing product feedback and bug reports with Apple. The same can be accessed here:

- [Bug Reporting - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)

Comment: Thanks. This form is really dated. I have to tell them what my OS is. Definitely prefer Microsoft's contextual feedback model—I assume they're able to pull that information from my Mac without needing to ask me.

Comment: @Crowder I have included the link to and some description about Radar, Apple's bug reporter used both internally and externally. That should better address your concern.

Comment: @Crowder It's not realistic to assume Apple would pull any info from your mac.  When reporting problems best to provide everything needed for someone to reproduce it without any knowledge about who it came from.

Comment: I wouldn’t start with any of these. 8 to 10 years ago these were the only way, support is far better now remotely (and far worse in store via Genius Bar)